# Почему раньше государственное учреждение называли «присутствием»?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

> *Степан Аркадьич в школе учился хорошо благодаря своим хорошим
> способностям, но был ленив и шалун и потому вышел из последних, но,
> несмотря на свою всегда разгульную жизнь, небольшие чины и нестарые
> годы, занимал почетное и с хорошим жалованьем место начальника в одном
> из московских присутствий. Место это он получил чрез мужа сестры
> Анны, Алексея Александровича Каренина, занимавшего одно из важнейших
> мест в министерстве, к которому принадлежало присутствие...*
>
> Лев Толстой, Анна Каренина.

Согласно Словарь русского языка Евгеньевой:

> **ПРИСУ́ТСТВИЕ**, -я, ср.
> 3. В дореволюционной России: государственное учреждение, а также помещение, занимаемое им.

Однако в этимологических словарях я это слово найти не могу.

Почему так называется? Потому что там кто-то присутствует? Кто? Чиновники? Государство? Посетители?

Какова этимология слова «присутствие» в таком значении?

---

**Дополнение 1**

Из комментария пользователя:

> И в современной России тоже: «Постоянное судебное присутствие
> арбитражного суда субъекта Российской Федерации является обособленным
> подразделением соответствующего арбитражного суда субъекта Российской
> Федерации вне места постоянного пребывания этого суда и осуществляет
> его полномочия».

Так же я нашёл в [Энциклопедическом словаре Брокгауза и Ефрона](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%A1%D0%91%D0%95/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5):

> Присутствие — на законодательном языке означает заседание
> какого-нибудь правительственного учреждения, но также служит и
> наименованием некоторых учреждений (воинские П., крестьянские П.,
> податные П., губернское по земским и городским делам П., соединенное
> П. первого и кассационных департаментов сената, высшее дисциплинарное
> П.), а иногда означает присутственную комнату (см.). Общие
> постановления об устройстве П. содержатся в Общем учреждении
> губернском (Св. Зак. т. II, ч. I, ст. 24—49).

Непонятно, почему заседание это присутствие.

---

**Дополнение 2**

Словарь Даля (сокращение — Eagle):

> ...где, заседать, сидеть членом или председателем в суде, или в
> совещательном правлении, месте. Присутствованье ср, действ. или сост.
> по глаг. Присутствие, то же, бытность где, заседанье где по должности,
> по службе; | судейская, или вообще комната, где заседают, присутствуют
> члены совещательного места; | самое заседанье это, время и все
> продолженье его... Присутствие устроено за стеклянными дверьми.
> Присутствие началось или открыто, и закрыто. Можно ли войти в
> присутствие? В каникулы у нас нет присутствия. В присутствии доклад
> идет. Рекрутское присутствие, для приема рекрут... Присутственное
> место, совещательное управленье, коему дано зерцало; заседанье для
> решенья дел. Присутственный день, час, когда бывает присутствие, когда
> члены заседают. Присутствующий в виде сущ. член присутствия,
> заседающий; советник, асессор, гласный заседатель и пр...

Таким образом получается, что «присутствовать» раньше имело значение заседать. Как место «присутствие» — это там, где заседают или на собрании, или просто сидят на своём рабочем месте по государственной службе. Значит у Толстого «присутствие», если понимать буквально, это место, где сидят на своих рабочих местах (присутствуют там) государственные служащие.

---

Может, кто-то что-то ещё скажет по теме?

Comment: И в современной России тоже: «Постоянное судебное присутствие арбитражного суда субъекта Российской Федерации является обособленным подразделением соответствующего арбитражного суда субъекта Российской Федерации вне места постоянного пребывания этого суда и осуществляет его полномочия».

Comment: @shampar Спасибо за информацию. Это интересно, что до сих пор термин сохранился. В этом определении это что-то похожее на филиал суда, или как бы на посольство. Можно сравнить с тем, что есть страна, и есть её посольства в других странах, и посредством посольств страна как бы присутствует в других странах, и с ней можно там взаимодействовать. Может, имеется ввиду, что центральная государственная власть как бы присутствует в регионах посредством этих «присутствий», и люди могут через них обращаться к власти.

Comment: @Артём Луговой Спасибо, что исправляете ошибки.

Comment: @shampar Ваш комментарий послужил хорошим примером, я дополнил вопрос после слова «Дополнение».

Comment: Да не за что)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Значит, у Толстого «присутствие», если     
понимать буквально, это место, где сидят 
на своих рабочих местах (присутствуют там) 
государственные служащие.
```

Видимо, именно так: присутствие - это присутственное место. Место, где присутствуют государственные мужи. Важно уже то, что они здесь присутствуют, их присутствие делает государственным само это место.

Этимология: от основы суть (быть - то, что есть, т.е. самое важное) образовано ст.-слав. действительное причастие наст. вр. сущий-"существующий", а от него с прист. при- прич. присущий-"присутствующий", которое потом стало восприниматься как прилагательное. Присутственный - для тех, кто важен. Получается, присутствие - присутственное место, место для важных людей = государственных.

Словарь исторических терминов:

> 1.присутствие -  присутственное место, в XVIII–XX вв. государственное учреждение, коллегиальный орган для совместного принятия решений.
> Члены П., одетые в форменное платье, церемонно собирались в
> определенное время в специальных помещениях, где считалось желательным
> иметь портрет императора. Они рассаживались за большим столом, на
> котором размещалось так называемое «зерцало» (то, что полагалось
> «созерцать») – трехгранная призма с текстами петровских указов,
> предписывающих соблюдение законов. По обсуждаемому вопросу сначала
> высказывались младшие члены П., затем – старшие; протокол обсуждения
> подписывался всеми членами в порядке старшинства. Важной особенностью
> функционирования П. было то, что дела зачитывались секретарями, а
> члены воспринимали текст на слух, так же как и формулировки решений по
> результатам опроса мнений (см. Коллегии).

" Российская государственность в терминах"
http://www.xn--80aacc4bir7b.xn--p1ai/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C-%

Английский Этимологический словарь - levee...гать

> 6. дневной прием при дворе с присутствием одних мужчин 7...

Толковый словарь Ушакова:

> - ПРИС'УТСТВЕННЫЙ , присутственная, присутственное ( офиц. •устар. ). Служебный, предназначенный для исполнения служебных обязанностей.
>   Присутственные дни. Присутственные часы. Присутственное время.
>   Присутственное место (правительственное учреждение или помещение,
>   занимаемое им; •устар. ). "Из готового уже дела велено было ему
>   сделать какое-то отношение в другое присутственное место." Гоголь.

Comment: Людмила, спасибо за ответ, я за него проголосовал и принял. Интересно, что вы разобрали этимологию присутствующий, от сущий. Я искал этимологию именно в нужном значении, интересно, что вы рассмотрели в обычном значении тоже. Я не понял вот это место: *«Английский Этимологический словарь — levee…гать: дневной прием при дворе с присутствием одних мужчин 7…»*. Тут что-то оборвано, вы могли бы поправить или разъяснить в комментарии.

Comment: А это я на Вокабуле словари просматривала и углядела в 2 словарях, что  levee переводится и как гать-насыпь, и как "приём": 6. дневной прием при дворе с присутствием одних мужчин 7. прием у президента и т. п. 8. ам. прием в честь почетного гостя 9. утренний выход (монарха) 10. собир. присутствующие при выходе монарха; собравшиеся на приеме     http://www.xn--80aacc4bir7b.xn--p1ai/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8/%D0%B0%D0%B0%D1%8D%D1%81/levee

Comment: Сочла, что и там похожее значение: важный приём=присутствие важных людей.